# PHP read user information from active directory

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I have to read some general information of user

like name, last name , email, department and etc. from an active directory with a PHP script

This is my code:

```
define('DOMAIN_FQDN', 'domain.ltd');
define('LDAP_SERVER', '192.168.30.1');

    $user = strip_tags($_POST['username']) .'@'. DOMAIN_FQDN;
    $pass = stripslashes($_POST['password']);
    $conn = ldap_connect("ldap://". LDAP_SERVER ."/");

    if (!$conn){
        $err = 'Could not connect to LDAP server';
    }else{
        //define('LDAP_OPT_DIAGNOSTIC_MESSAGE', 0x0032);

        ldap_set_option($conn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
        ldap_set_option($conn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

        $bind = @ldap_bind($conn, $user, $pass);

        ldap_get_option($conn, LDAP_OPT_DIAGNOSTIC_MESSAGE, $extended_error);

        if ($bind){
            //$base_dn = array("CN=Users,DC=". join(',DC=', explode('.', DOMAIN_FQDN)), "OU=Users,OU=People,DC=". join(',DC=', explode('.', DOMAIN_FQDN)));
            $base_dn = array("DC=". join(',DC=', explode('.', DOMAIN_FQDN)), "OU=*,DC=". join(',DC=', explode('.', DOMAIN_FQDN)));
            $result = ldap_search(array($conn,$conn), $base_dn, "(cn=*)");
            if (!count($result)){
                $err = 'Unable to login: '. ldap_error($conn);
            }else{
                foreach ($result as $res){
                    $info = ldap_get_entries($conn, $res);
                    print_r($info);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This code `print_r($info);` returns a array with a lot of data which means my connection is working good..

but there isn't any thing about user

**i need to get current logged in user data**

Is this wrong or I must put some more options on it?

the user data in active directory:

[image]

Comment: Without checking, your base DN seems fine. However, your filter (`(cn=*)`)  accepts all entries. This reveals the underlying problem: You do not mention any filter criteria for this method to begin with. There is not way to provide user input to select a specific user. So your method does the only sensible thing: printing _all_ entries.

Comment: @hagello how can i change `((cn=*))` to one user data.all example i found do like this!!

Comment: @peinman What's your input data? The surname? The email address? A combination?

Comment: @hagello i active directory i saved all information but for retrieval i need email and first name and last name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to decide which accounts you want to read. Using the filter `(cn=*)`, you are telling AD to give you every object where the `cn` attribute has a value. That will match to almost *every AD object in your domain*, including computers, which I don't think you want.

If you want to find all users on the domain, you can use this:

```
(objectClass=user)
```

If you want to find one specific user, the query will depend on what identifier you have for that user. For example, if you know their username (let's say "PeimanF"), then the query would look like this:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=PeimanF))
```

Comment: is this work on a limited user? my account is a normal user on active directory not `administrator`

Comment: but the `(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=PeimanF))` in my above code return `Array ( [count] => 0 ) Array ( [count] => 0 ) `

Comment: That means you don't have a user account with the username "PeimanF" in your domain :)

Comment: but this is that user i logged in some lines upper!! now i changed your suggestion with this `(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=$user))` in my sample code but return `Array ( [count] => 0 ) Array ( [count] => 0 )` again :| this mean user can login but not exists

Comment: What format is `$user`? Is it just the plain username, or is it DOMAIN\username? Or is it username@domain? That query will only work with just the username, without the domain.

Comment: `$user` is `peimanf@domain.ltd` but i tested `peimanf` and `DOMAIN\peimanf` and none of them working!! is there a way to debug this? why this dont show any error :(

Comment: If the format of the username is `peimanf@domain.ltd`, then you need to search by `userPrincipalName`. Like this: `(&(objectClass=user)(userPrincipalName=$user))`

Comment: There are no errors because you're telling AD, "give me every account where this attribute equals this", and there just aren't any. The search itself is successful, so there's no reason to throw an exception.

Comment: `(&(objectClass=user)(userPrincipalName=$user))` return `Array ( [count] => 0 ) Array ( [count] => 0 )` again.

Comment: Do you have access to Active Directory Users and Computers? Can you look up what the `userPrincipalName` is? (it's right at the top of the 'Account' tab)

Comment: image of account tab added to main post. Thank you

Comment: So does your `$user` variable equal `peimanf@src.ir`? The resulting query should be `(&(objectClass=user)(userPrincipalName=peimanf@src.ir))`

Comment: the problem was in $base_dn, i changed it and now it return my needed data.

Comment: That will do it! :)